# @KafkaListener concurrency multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to create a concurrent `@KafkaListener` which can handle multiple topics each with different number of partitions.

I have noticed that Spring-Kafka only initializes one consumer per partition for the topic with most partitions.

Example: I have set concurrency to 8. I got a `@KafkaListener` listening to the following topics. Topic A has the most partitions - 5, so Spring-Kafka initializes 5 consumers. I expected Spring-Kafka to initialize 8 consumers, which is the maximum allowed according to my concurrency property.

- Topic A has 5 partitions
- Topic B has 3 partitions
- Topic C has 1

What is the technical reason for not initializing more consumers?

How do I bypass this, such that I can initialize more consumers using the `@KafkaListener` annotation? (if possible at all)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a listener is configured to listen to multiple topics, each consumer instance listens on all topics; Spring indeed starts 8 consumers (in this case), but the way those partitions are actually distributed across the consumers is controlled by Kafka's group management:

[image]

[image]

So you end up with 3 idle consumers in this case.

It might be possible to provide a custom `partition.assignment.strategy` to do the distribution the way you want, but I've never looked into that.

**EDIT**

I just tested with the `RoundRobinAssignor`...

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
```

and...

[image]

Comment: Looks like the `RoundRobinAssignor` does what you want. See my edit.

Comment: I have tested `RoundRobinAssignor` in my own project. It works as expected. The concurrency is utilized 100% - All the consumes are assigned partitions.

Comment: I was stuck while trying to achieve concurrency when using a @StreamListener (or @KafkaListener) with a topic pattern - at least in some cases, a single thread/listener would service all matching topics (1 partition each), and the others had nothing to do. But configuring the RoundRobinAssignor gave me exactly what I wanted!

This appears to be a critical detail when using a pattern to match topics with concurrency.  Docs/examples I found mentioned the need to configure the metadata refresh with topic patterns, but I don't think I saw any references partition assignment strategy.